What is the ethymology of the word　どのこと?
After finding out his friend has been talking to his crush, the protagonist says to his friend:
余計なこと言ってないだろうな
"You didn't say weird stuff, right?"
To which the friend replies
どのことだろか まあ俺は噓はつかないがな!
What is the word どのこと trying to say exactly? "what kind of stuff"?

Are you asking for the etymology (where the word comes from) or for usage (what it means and how to use it)?

Since other answerers have already said that this is not question about etymology, I will mention that the term which you probably wanted is semantics.

Your question is about usage yet your title is about etymology. I will assume you were wondering about usage here.
You can think of どのこと as どの 'which' and こと 'thing'. Here, the friend is saying "What kind of (unnecessary) stuff, I wonder?". This followed by "Well, I didn't say any lies!" seems to imply that he did in fact say what the protagonist hoped they would not. By the way, 余計なこと is not really "weird thing", it's more so "unnecessary things", as in "don't say anything you shouldn't say".

This is not an etymology (you seem to be confused about what that word means in English), but you may find it useful to think about this way:
どれ is "what/which one", i.e. the question equivalent of "this one" これ / "that one" それ / "the other one" あれ. These words make up one of many so-called kosoado series.
Adding のこと to give どれのこと has the usual nuance.
どれの is contracted to, and lexicalized as, どの. Generally we think of この・その・あの・どの as another kosoado series. One problem is that the English translations tend to look the same, but they are grammatically distinct. But this analysis makes a certain kind of sense if we consider that どれ and こと are nouns (or pronouns), and の here is the usual particle の used for categorizing or describing one noun via another.

When I say that this is not an etymology, I specifically mean:

I cannot say with any certainty that どの etc. derive from どれの etc. But it's a useful way to help remember the two series and how they work.

While the term "word" is somewhat problematic in linguistics (especially when making comparisons across languages), I imagine that almost everyone would consider どのこと to be two words - so I can't give an etymology of "the word". I could try to talk about how どの is formed or where it comes from (as above), but your question is apparently really about grammar and usage.



Re: the -no set for the こそあど series, we see instances of kono and kano (precursor to modern ano) way back in the Kojiki of 712 and the Man'yōshū of 759. While I cannot find Old Japanese attestations of iduno (the precursor to modern dono), the earlier existence of other -no words alongside -re words suggests that these are simply stems こそあど + various endings like れ・の・こ etc., and that the -no series is not the product of a contraction.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Yes, this no is originally simply genitive case particle no. Some pages about pronouns from certain book: 136, 137, ... until 143, 245, 246, 247.

@Arfrever -- Odd, on page 143, the author (Vovin?) claims that distal ka only shows up from Early Middle Japanese - but the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 entry here at Kotobank shows citations of kare and kano in the Man'yōshū. Not sure what to make of that. — Anyway, thank you for the links!

@EiríkrÚtlendi Bjarke Frellesvig on page 139 claimed that kare is attested once and ka twice (all 3 cases in Man'yōshū).

Alexander Vovin (2020, page 261) has different analysis of this no: 「They have a modifier form in -nǝ, which looks like an unextended stem, followed by a genitive case marker -nǝ, but in reality it is not the genitive case marker, but the attributive form n-ǝ of the defective verb n-. Thus, e.g., historically proximal modifier form kǝnǝ < *kǝ n-ǝ ‘this DV-ATTR.’」.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Some pages from Alexander Vovin's book: 261, 262, 278, 279, ... until 282.

If the -no series doesn't come from a contraction, but it does represent a genitive case particle... does that imply that  れ・こ also have (or had) independent functions? What might those be? Also, might those older appearances of kare / kano possibly relate to modern 彼・彼女?

Vovin was hypothesizing that -re comes from plural marker -ra + -i. About -kǝ, he wrote (pages 268-269): 「The proximal demonstrative pronoun kǝkǝ ‘here’ is a combination of the unextended stem kǝ- of the proximal demonstrative pronoun kǝ / kǝre and the obsolete word *kǝ ‘place.’76」 and note 76 has: 「It is possible that *kǝ ‘place’ in kǝkǝ ‘here’ and sǝkǝ ‘there’ is a result of progressive vowel
assimilation, cf. -ko ‘place’ with kō-rui vowel /o/ in miya-ko ‘capital (lit.: palace-place),’ where the conditions for such progressive assimilation are not present; ...

… as well as -ka ‘place’ in ar-i-ka ‘place to be’ and sum-i-ka ‘place to live,’ where -ka can be a truncation of *-kau (> -ko).」 For other words with these suffixes (-ko, -ka), see 処.

For modern 彼・彼女, see etymology sections here and here.
